# what are the normalization rules for properties in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-directive

I ran into a silly issue recently with a component that uses a `title` property to bind the *title* of that component.
I forgot that `title` was a known HTML attribute and my users started seeing tooltips with the title over their components.

At first, I just changed the property name to not conflict. But then I remembered that in AngularJS, there are [rules about normalization for directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization).

I searched (using the search function) the Angular 6+ documentation and I couldn't find the word *normalization* in there.
I also tested and there seems to be some normalization available, at least using `data-`.

My question is: 
**Is normalization officially supported in Angular 6+? and where can I find documentation for it?**

I created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-directive-normalization) with the following key components to highlight that using `data-name="bob"` is apparently equivalent to `name="bob"` :

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{title}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() title: string;
}
```

```html
<hello data-title="bob"></hello>
<hello title="bob"></hello>
```

Comment: I am not sure if [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1598) and [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoid-namespace-clashes-with-directives-1f00d62de445) partially answer your question.

Comment: @ConnorsFan yeah, in the end, I ended up specifying my property with a name that is not in conflict. My question was more specifically about what normalization is happening in Angular 2+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a directive that has an input that could be in conflict with an attribute for the parent element you have 3 options.

1. Change the directive's input to a non-conflicting name.
2. Use binding notation

   ```
   <button title="PushMe" titleTesting [title]="'dont push me'">Push this</button>
   ```
3. Use attribute notation.

   ```
   <button [attr.title]="'PushMe'" titleTesting title="dont push me">Push this</button>
   ```

Directive code used in above template:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[titleTesting]'
})
export class TitleTestDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() title: string;
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.title);
  }
}
```

Finally if the values should be the same and is a constant defined in the template then proceed as normal as both the element and your directive would get the same value, example:

```
<button titleTesting title="dont push me">Push this</button>
```

See also [Binding syntax: An overview](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview) and [Property binding or interpolation?](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation), [attribute binding](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-directive-normalization-q4kb9u), and a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-directive-normalization-q4kb9u).

---

### Normalization

In short [angular](https://angular.io) does not support or do anything with normalization. You had directive listed but had a component example, a component would not have any conflicting attributes/inputs which is why I chose to model an example using directives.

[data-](https://w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) is an HTML5 construct. [angular](https://angular.io) does not do anything with that directly. If you do include [data-](https://w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) though it will still bind as expected to the Input but it won't be set on any html specific attribute. Example: `data-title="some title"`. Based on the [data- documentation](https://w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) this is expected behavior.

You can supply both a [data-](https://w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) and a non `data-` element of the same type for different values but the order in which they appear is important. Example:

```
<button titleTesting title="Push me" data-title="DOn't push me">Push this</button>
```

Comment: thank you for you comment but it is not the heart of my question (I am very well aware of the syntax). Further, using `[name]="'bob'"` is 4 extra characters that do not bring any value. the `name="bob"` is the correct syntax for binding to static data.

Comment: I really appreciate your time, but you are missing the point of my question here. I know all about the 100 other ways of doing what I am already doing. My specific question is about _normalization_. It **is** happening, as my example shows, if you prepend `data-` to your property, it works. But I can't find documentation about this. I am also going to clarify that I am using a _component_ not a _directive_ (I thought the example was sufficient).

Comment: thanks for that clarification. And I guess you are right. I was just surprised that in AngularJS there was an entire section of the directive documentation dedicated to explaining what was happening while Angular 2+ does not seem to mention that at all. So, the answer is: the browser does that, not Angular? is that all browsers? just more wondering for future reference...

Comment: @EricLiprandi - In short [tag:angular] does not support or do anything with normalization. You had directive listed but had a component example, a component would not have any conflicting attributes/inputs which is why I chose to model an example using directives.

Comment: @EricLiprandi - `data-` is an html5 construct. See also https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp. [tag:angular] does not do anything with that directly.  If you do include `data-` though it will still bind as expected to the `Input` but it won't be set on any html specific attribute. Example: `data-title="some title"`. Based on the `data-` documentation this is expected behavior.

Comment: @EricLiprandi - although you can supply both a `data-` and a non `data-` element of the same type for different values but the order in which they appear is important. Example: `<button titleTesting title="Push me" data-title="DOn't push me">Push this</button>`